# How to access session variables in class library in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I assigned a value in `Session["MyVariable"]` but unable to access the data from `Session["MyVariable"]` in class library. I have given system.web reference to class library and I used system.web namespace in my class file.I have written the code to get session data as

```
if(HttpContext.Current != null)
string s = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyVariable"].ToString();
```

Where I am **getting HttpContext.Current is null**

Please help me to solve this problem and let me know the way to get session values in class library

Comment: From where do you call this method?

Comment: I assigned in a Session["MyVariable"] in aspx.cs page and I am trying to access Session["MyVariable"]  in class file belongs to class library which is another project

Comment: @RosiReddy: you still haven't answered the question. From where do you try to call the method in the class library? Is that method called from the webapplication/website or not? If you call it f.e. from a windows application there is no `HttpContext`.

Comment: in my aplication, individual user has individual database. so i have to pass the user's database name to connection class which is in other project

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I called it from web application

Comment: try `string s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyVariable"].ToString();`